# Azure key vault values inside AKS

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I've been building Azure Bicep files with the goal of having our infrastructure codified.

All is going well except for AKS. Reading and experimenting I think I have two options.

AKS has pods with Nodejs or .net services running in them which need environment variables like database connection strings. These can be passed in at the deploy stage of each node/.net or they can be 'included' in each AKS instance.

Am I on the right track and does one have advantages over the other?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IaC Code for your AKS should not be mixed with deployment code of workload (your Nodejs or .Net Pods).

I would also not recommend to use ENV variables for secrets and connections strings. Kubernetes upstream decided that CSI (Container Storage Interface) is the way to go.

With that being said, you can write a Bicep deployment that deploys AKS & Azure Key Vault. Enable the `azureKeyvaultSecretsProvider` add-on for the AKS to sync secrets from Azure KeyVault to Kubernetes [secrets](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/docs/configurations/sync-with-k8s-secrets/) or directly as [files into pods](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/docs/getting-started/usage/).

After this you write you workload deployment of Nodejs and .Net Pods and refer the AZURE KEY VAULT PROVIDER FOR SECRETS STORE CSI DRIVER. This also make you more independent if you create more cluster etc.

Comment: @Phiip Welz, Thanks for that, CSI is now on the study list. The first part about mixing IaC and deployments i think was my poor wording in my question. Thanks again

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, links are updated ;)